# Using PHP filename as argument for the file itself

Tags: php, .htaccess

Yesterday I was wondering about the possibility to use, in PHP, a file's name as argument for the file itself... Basically, I've a file named "file.php", and whenever, through the browser, I request any file i.e. "test1.php", I call the file "file.php" passing as argument the name of the previous file. Is possible to do something like this?

```
<Files *.php>
    //I call the "anotherpath/file.php" file passing as argument the filename of the file called before
    //i.e. Call anotherpath/file.php?arg=filename of the "virtual" file
</Files>
```

"test1.php" (which isn't even in the server) calls "anotherpath/file.php", and this one can *access* the "test1" string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd setup a query `?q=any` that takes you to `file.php` and add a rewrite rule in `.htaccess`. I wouldn't keep the `.php` extension tho.

Comment: Doesn't this become available under `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in the root directory and add this code to it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now, this will redirect all requests to index.php. Now, in index.php add this code,

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;
?>
```

This will print the requested URL into web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on using rules, another option is to store the last page in the session. Something like;

```
$lastpage = $_SESSION['LastPage'];
$_SESSION['LastPage'] = 'this page.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

send the file name in url:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?p=page1';?>" >page1</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?p=page2';?>" >page2</a>
<div id="main-content" >
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['p']))
      $page = $_GET['p'].".php";
    else
      $page = "default.php"
    include($page);
</div>
```